# FIFO programmed main thread dispatcher?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, delegates, fifo

To begin with, I'm using unity. Which makes me stuck with .NET 3.5. I'm currently working on a server program which uses the `Socket` object's asynchronous methods (E.G. `BeginReceive`, `BeginAccept`, `BeginReceiveFrom` etc.). When the server receives a packet from a client, this packet is received on a worker thread. Now I'm left with some data on a worker thread, and I want the main thread to process this data using a function that I specify. I implemented that:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyDispatcherClass
{
    public delegate void MyDel();
    private readonly Queue<MyDel> commands = new Queue<MyDel>();
    Object lockObj = new object ();

    public void Add(MyDel dc)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            commands.Enqueue (dc);
        }
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            while (commands.Count > 0)
            {
                commands.Dequeue().Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would use it this way:

```
// As a global variable:
MyDispatcherClass SomeDispatcher = new MyDispatcherClass ();

//The function that I want to call:
public void MyFunction (byte[] data)
{
    // Do some stuff on the main thread
}

//When I receive a message on a worker thread I do that:
SomeDispatcher.Add (()=> MyFunction (byte[] data)); //Asuume that "data" is the message I received from a client

//Each frame on the main thread I call:
SomeDispatcher.Invoke ();
```

After some research, I found that the `lock` statement does not guarantee a %100 FIFO implementation. Which is not what I wanted, sometimes this may cause a total server breakdown! I want to achieve the same result with a %100 guarantee that data will be processed in the same order it was received from a client. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: do you get all the data from one client in a single thead? If so, you could add an `AddRange` method to your dispatcher which takes a `IEnumerable<MyDel>` as argument and add them in the same lock body.

Comment: I examined this before. I receive data from each client 1 by 1, and the thread I'm calling SomeDispatcher.Add from may be constantly changing even for each client(This is the implementation made by Microsoft).

Answer (score 1):

Threads will run in whatever order they want, so you can't force the order going into the queue.  But you can put in more data into the queue than just what you will eventually be processing.

If you add a DateTime, (or even just an int with a specified order) to the data being sent you can sort your queue on that when you pull data from it, (and possibly not pull any data less than 0.5 seconds old to give time for other threads to write their data.)

Normally when dealing with client-server relationships each thread represents one client so you don't have to worry about this as commands are FIFO within the thread, (although they might not be when 2 different clients are sending messages.)

Do you close and re-open the socket on the same client? that could make it use different threads.  If you need a specific order and are sending things fairly soon after each other it might be better to leave the socket open.

Comment: "Normally when dealing with client-server relationships each thread represents one client", Wrong. This is the cheap implementation of a server. Using the asynchronous functions of `Socket`s in c# doesn't do that. "Do you close and re-open the socket on the same client", of course I don't.

Comment: asynchronous functions are designed to run when they can instead of right now in the order you want.  Can you switch to synchronous versions, or add the DateTime/processing order counter on the client end as part of the data you are sending?

Comment: "Can you switch to synchronous versions?": Has a huge impact on performance and results in a non-scalable server, so I simply can't.  "Can you add the DateTime/processing order counter on the client end as part of the data you are sending?": Unfortunately, this is an API for games.Thus, I'm trying to reduce the amount of data sent as much as possible(I'm using a 1 byte UDP header maximum to solve all the problems in socket programming, manage all connections ,assign unique ID for each client and have a connection handshake), so I'll send more bytes if I'm completely frustrated!

Comment: UDP is also not ideal if things need to be in an exact order.  TCP guarantees FIFO and that every packet will make it to the destination. UDP does not.

Comment: There is a reason for the performance impact on TCP and Synchronous programming.  They take care of the problems you are running into right now.  What you are doing is great if the packet order doesn't matter, but if it does you have to bite the bullet and use the specs that guarantee FIFO, or do something on your end to make sure it doesn't care, (re-order later, or use absolute values rather than relative changes.)

Comment: I couldn't metion TCP because of the maximum characters, I'm using a 4 byte header to deal with all this stuff. and if 2 TCP packets are swapped that is what may cause the server to break down, so I'm just making sure that won't happen. They take care of their part, I want to take care of my part: Make sure no data gets un-ordered while dispatching.

Comment: You can also use Synchronous methods and still not wait for them to be done.  You just have to implement a queue on the client side and have it run in it's own thread. That way you can send messages to the server in order, but not block the UI.